# Djnago ORM выбор из двух таблиц

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте! У меня есть две модели связанные между собой через ForeignKey

```
class User(models.Model):
    object = models.ForeignKey(Object, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Object(models.Model):
    count = FloatField()
```

Подскажите, как выбрать всех User для Object у которых count меньше определенного значения? Я пробовал так, но возвращается пустой queryset:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    ...
    return queryset.filter(object_id=object__location__distance_lt=10)
```

Comment: Зачем Вы пишите `object_id=` ? И, по-моему, нужно написать так `object__count__lt=10`. Но это не точно )

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Моя невнимательность меня же и погубит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если правильно понял, то так

```
.filter(object__count__lt=10)
```